# SoftLayer API: How to get list of questionId and answers values in itemCategoryQuestionAnswer object

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

SoftLayer API SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Subnet.itemCategoryQuestionAnswers

is a type of SoftLayer_Container_Product_Item_Category_Question_Answer,

How can I get a list of possible

questionId/ answer values based on categoryId and catogoryCode in SoftLayer_Container_Product_Item_Category_Question_Answer  ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the questions that are associated with an item category with the following method:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Item_Category/getQuestions

e.g. REST request

```
https://$username:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Item_Category/312/getQuestions

Method: Get
```

"312" refers to categoryID, replace it with the categoryId that you wish.

I hope this information can help you.